# Aggregate data with custom group function

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate

I have a data frame and I want to apply an aggregate function on some of it's columns value, grouping them by a custom key.

I have a custom function that takes as input a row of the data frame and generates the key. How can I call the `aggregate` function (or `sapply`, `tapply`...)

Something like that basically:

```
GetRowKey <- function(row_value) { GetRowKey = row_value[1] % 5 }

aggregate(my_data, GetRowKey, FUN=max)
```

With an Input like this:

```
1,1
6,2
1,3
7,3
12,5
11,8
```

I'll have the following results:

```
1,8
2,5
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your custom function definition and how you use it inside the `aggregate` function. Could you provide a reproducible example and desired output?

Comment: Now based on the example data you provided, what is the `GetRowKey` function supposed to do? I don't understand that yet.

Comment: Sorry the example was wrong I've just edited it. It returns a key that is used to group the data together before we aggregate it.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that in the question. What I was asking for was more of an explanation, how you derive the result from the example input, since it's not clear to me what you mean with key generation. And, your example input hast two columns, while `mydata[,2:3]` implies that you are using some data with at least 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you should use `%%`, not just a single `%` symbol. In my opinion, you don't really need a custom function here.  It's easier to substitute your function body straight into the `aggregate()` function.

```
> d <- read.table(text = "1,1
   6,2
   1,3
   7,3
   12,5
   11,8", sep = ",")

> aggregate(d[[2]], d[1] %% 5, max)
#   V1 x
# 1  1 8
# 2  2 5
```

As is stands, your custom function does not return anything.  If you were to adjust it to

```
> GetRowKey <- function(row_value) { row_value[1] %% 5 }
```

we can use it in `aggregate()` as follows,

```
> aggregate(dat[[2]], GetRowKey(dat[1]), max)
  V1 x
1  1 8
2  2 5
```

Comment: +1, That makes sense. Note that the desired result looks slightly different, but perhaps just a formatting problem in the question.

Comment: How would you give a custom function as an input instead of `d[1] %% 5` (the modulo in `GetRowKey` is just for the sake of the example).

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks that does the trick, the example works. On my data I have an issue `'by' must be a list`, even though my keys look like they are in a list. Any idea why ?